# If A is polynomial time reducible to B does that imply not(A) is polynomial reducible to not(B)

Tags: complexity-theory, np-complete, np-hard, np

$A\leq_p B \iff \bar{A}\leq_p \bar{B}$ (if A is polynomial time reducible to B does that imply that complement of A is polynomial reducible to complement of B)

I was told that this is the case based on the definition of $\leq_p$ but I am having trouble proving this.

Comment: I think the proof differs a bit depending on the type of polytime reduction we're talking about (there are multiple). Could you provide _your_ definition of a polytime reduction?

Comment: @Discretelizard From what I understand a polytime reduction means that we can transform the inputs of A in to the inputs of B in polynomial time

Comment: That doesn't sound like a _formal_ definition. Surely whoever told you that 'this is case based on the definition of $\leq_p$' told you what this definition is. (btw, we have MathJax on this site, so everything between '$'-signs renders as mathmode TeX. Please don't use it in titles, though, they are used in places without TeX rendering)

Comment: I was never really given a formal definition, just shown how they were "supposed" to be done. The definition I have been going off is the Many-one reduction found on wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-one_reduction)

Comment: 'I was never really given a formal definition' Jikes. I'm sorry to hear that. You did pick the 'right' formalization, though, in the sense that I think this property is relatively simple to prove for that definition. I also think that instead of completely answering this, it is better for you to try it yourself, with some hints.

Comment: Hint 1: The Wikipedia definition can be tricky. The following might be a bit easier: $A\leq_p B$, i.e. $A$ is polynomial time reducible to $B$ if and only if there exists a polynomial time computable function $f$ (i.e. an algorithm) such that for every instance $I$ of problem $A$ is a 'YES-instance' if and only if $f(I)$ is a 'YES-instance' of problem $B$. Hint 2: Take another good look at the definition from 'complement' and see what changes in the definition of $\leq_p$ when you replace A and B by their complements.

Comment: I figured it out thank you for the help

Answer (score 3):

In case you were wondering, the answer is yes.

Here is the reasoning.

**Lemma**: Let $f$ be a reduction from $A$ to $B$. Then $f$ is also a reduction from $\overline A$ to $\overline B$.
**Proof**: By the definition of a reduction, $f$ maps $A$ to $B$ and $f$ maps the complement of $A$ to the complement of $B$. So $f$ maps the complement of the complement of $A$, which is $A$ itself, to $B$, which is the complement of the complement of $B$. By the definition of a reduction again, $f$ is a reduction from the complement of $A$ to the complement of $B$. QED.

Suppose $A$ is polynomial-time reducible to $B$. Let $f$ be a polynomial reduction from $A$ to $B$. The lemmas shows that $f$ is also a reduction from the complement of $A$ to the complement of $B$. Since $f$ is polynomial-time, $\overline A$ is polynomial-time reduced to $\overline B$ by $f$.

With $A$ replaced by $\overline A$ and $B$ by $\overline B$, the above paragraph also shows $\overline A$ is polynomial-time reducible to $\overline B$ implies $A$ is polynomial-time reduced to $B$.

The above two paragraphs shows the equivalence of $A\leq_p B$ and $\overline{A}\leq_p \overline{B}$.

Comment: @Apass.Jack I’ve added some clarifying details. I’m not sure how better to explain it, other than the fact that the if and only if ensures that the complement holds the same relationship.

Comment: "f is a polynomial time reduction if and only if a yes instance of B corresponds to a yes instance of f(A)". This statement does not make much sense since f might not be surjective.

Comment: I just took the liberty to revamp this answer, since it does not make sense to write another answer for a simple question like this.

Comment: Your answer is much better, all credit should be yours @Apass.Jack. You’re right that I should have defined f better. Thanks!