# How to prove coNP is closed under reverse Karp Reduction?

Tags: complexity-theory, reductions

Is it true that $A \leq_k B \land B \in \mathsf{coNP} \implies A \in \mathsf{coNP}$?

If so, how would you go about proving it?

Comment: Use the definitions.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus do you honestly believe your comment has any value whatsoever?

Comment: @Zarwan Definitely. It has worked in the past several times.

Comment: @sargeras, does [this answer](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/106458/91753) ring a bell?

Comment: @Apass.Jack Yes that actually does help. I wasn't initially sure if $A \leq_{k} B \implies \overline{A} \leq_{k} \overline{B}$ holds. Thanks!